# Extjs - getting 'TypeError: name is undefined' when add chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

When replacing the chart some other such grid all is well.
Maybe there is sort of a mistake in the declaration chart?
My chart page (projecttaskstatistics):

```
Ext.define('yTrack.view.project.Task.Statistics' , {
    extended: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
    alias: 'widget.projecttaskstatistics',
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    animate: true,
    store: 'Tasks.Timehistory',
    axes: [{
        type: 'Time',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['time'],
        dateFormat: 'G',
        title: 'Use of time',
        grid: true
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['user_name'],
        title: 'Users'
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        axis: 'bottom',
        highlight: true,
        tips: {
            trackMouse: true,
            width: 140,
            height: 28
            renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                this.setTitle(storeItem.get('user_name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('time') + ' views');
            }
        },
        label: {
            display: 'insideEnd',
            field: 'time',
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('G:i'),
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            color: '#333',
            'text-anchor': 'middle'
        },
        xField: 'user_name',
        yField: 'time'
    }]
});
```

I am can find error. Help me.

Comment: Can you provide the line # that error is thrown from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors there are, indeeed.

There is the missing colon, as noted by Drew.

Furthermore, your should fix this line:

```
extended: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
```

to this:

```
extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
```

You don't need to require a class you extend, though.

Comment: Yes I missed that - extended needs to be extend

Comment: My parent window `
title: 'Task Statistics',
layout: 'fit',
items: [
       {
        xtype: 'form',
        layout: 'column',
        items: [
               {
                title: 'Tasks project',
                xtype: 'projecttasklist',
                border: true,
                padding: 5,
                columnWidth: .6
               },
               {
               title: 'Task Statistics',
               xtype: 'projecttaskstatistics',
               border: true,
               padding: 5,
               columnWidth:.99
               }

Comment: I'm find error. Need Add `requires:['yTrack.view.project.Task.Statistics'],` in parent window

Answer (score 0):

Your missing comma in your code (after height: 28 in your tips config), try this and let me know if it works:

```
Ext.define('yTrack.view.project.Task.Statistics' , { extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart', alias: 'widget.projecttaskstatistics', width: 500, height: 300, animate: true, store: 'Tasks.Timehistory', axes: [{
        type: 'Time',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['time'],
        dateFormat: 'G',
        title: 'Use of time',
        grid: true
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['user_name'],
        title: 'Users' }], series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    axis: 'bottom',
    highlight: true,
    tips: {
        trackMouse: true,
        width: 140,
        height: 28,
        renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
            this.setTitle(storeItem.get('user_name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('time') + ' views');
        }
    },
    label: {
        display: 'insideEnd',
        field: 'time',
        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('G:i'),
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        color: '#333',
        'text-anchor': 'middle'
    },
    xField: 'user_name',
    yField: 'time' }] });
```

Comment: Did not work if the unit is replaced by: `Ext.define('yTrack.view.project.Task.Statistics' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.projecttaskstatistics',
    store: 'Tasks.Timehistory',
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'user_name', width: 200},
        {header: 'Time',  dataIndex: 'time', width: 150}
    ]
});` everything works, then there is a problem in this module.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue and it got resolved with the below change

Remove **ext-all-debug.js**

```
<script src="ext-4.2.0.663/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

add **ext-all.js**

```
<script src="ext-4.2.0.663/ext-all.js"></script>
```

it seems that it is a bug in ExtJs Debugger .js file.

Try it.hope it will get resolve.